# Set a Bitmap to a Window-Object using wxPyhton

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

I want to set a Bitmap to a hole Window-Object. 
I tested to do it with

```
__bmp = wx.Bitmap('/images/settings.bmp')
dc = wx.WindowDC(the_window)
dc.DrawBitmap(__bmp,0,0)
```

but this doesn't work. Some tipps?

One Problem is, that after creating the WindowDC object and putting the bitmap to it,
the bitmap is "destroyed"

```
__mybmp = dc.GetAsBitmap()
print __mybmp.GetHeight()
```

output

> 0

crazy?!

Comment: you may need "r" before quote. Do you know your wx.Bitmap object is created properly? And, this is on OnPaint handler right? If so, the code looks good to me. I have very similar code (except BufferedPaintDC instead of WindowDC) that is working for me.

Comment: The "r" is for a raw string and would only be useful if the OP was using backslashes instead of forward slashes.

Comment: Yeah, I know that the Bitmap object is created, and the bitmap behind is the right one (only by get some information about the bitmap with 
__bmp.GetHeight() and it returned the right high